# FlowForce - monitoring and alerting tool

Tags: server, alerts

I had to configure AppDynamics alerts in the past for Java applications I worked for. 
I also heard of Nagios, but I am not very sure how that works.

Now, I need to configure alerts for a FlowForce Server, but I don't believe it can be integrated with AppDynamics or Nagios.

I saw FlowForce allow me to send some alerts, like when a step of a job fails, but I would like to have some server alerts, like, for instance, if the license expires and, as a result, the server is automatically shut down.

I am wondering the best way to achieve it.

I am running it on a Windows environment BTW.

Suggestions are welcome.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer on the Flow Force online help (https://manual.altova.com/flowforceserver/flowforceserver/)

The Flow Force is deployed as two servers, which in a window env, can be started and stopped as windows services (can be found via "Control Panel">"Administrative Tools">Services). With this information, I can monitor them via NAGIOS.